# remove hints in jetbrains

Tags: c++, ide, clion, jetbrains-ide

How to remove this hints in CLion in my case?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File > Settings > Editor > Inlay hints [C++]
```

Comment: @andriy-byte Most welcome, use the Check mark if the answer worked for you.